# Html.RadioButtonFor without radiobutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I want to a form with radiobuttons in it.
Here you can see what I mean:
[image]

As you can see you have the options "Graphic Design, Photo Design, ..".
What I want to do is when you click on one of them, that the background-color of the text changes.

For the radiobuttons I have this:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.AfstudeerrichtingID, 1)<img src="~/Content/images/img1.png"/>Graphic Design (CMO)
```

How can I hide the circles?

niels

Comment: You can do that using css.

Comment: And how can I add a a class to that radioubtton?

Comment: `@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.AfstudeerrichtingID, 1, new { @class = "noRadioButton" })`